# multiplying bx and cx [ASM 8086]

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication, x86-16

I would like to multiplying bx and cx,but it doesnt works like I use ax

```
mov ax,0AFh
mov cx,0AFh
mul cx
```

my try to multiplying bx and cx

```
mov bx,Ah
mov cx,5h
mul cx
"???????"
```

For multiplying bx and cx I think I must use a temp register. Can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: In `mov bx,Ah`, the source is the AH register, not an immediate constant.  Perhaps you meant `0Ah`?  Also, just read the manual for http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html, or any other instruction that's not doing what you expect.  See also links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: @Shift_Left: The question says 8086, but `imul r16, r/m16` was only introduced with 386.  The result isn't really signed or unsigned: only the high half of the full result differs.  Two-operand IMUL does set flags based on signed stuff, but otherwise there's no need for MUL if you don't need the upper half of the result.  IMUL is definitely the right choice if you don't actually have to target ancient hardware (or emu8086).

Comment: @PeterCordes I removed my comment as it was completely out of context. Never would have thought I'd be pulling **The 8086 Book** off my shelf that I bought 39 yrs ago.

Comment: @Shift_Left: I wish I didn't know crap like this, but people keep asking SO questions about 8086 (e.g. with emu8086).  16-bit (and MS-DOS) questions are bad enough, but I think 8086's lack of features makes it harder to learn, not easier.  Anyway, [this instruction-set guide from the NASM manual](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html) documents when each form of every instruction was introduced.  It's one of the many useful links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: Knowing original 8086 assembly went out of fashion when IBM launched the [PC/AT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer/AT) in 1984. 32 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
mov bx, 0Ah
mov cx, 5h
push ax
mov ax, bx
mul cx
mov bx, ax
pop ax
;at this point, ax is unchanged, result is in bx.
```

Or, if you want to be fancy, try this:

```
mov bx, 0Ah
mov cx, 5h
xchg ax, bx
mul cx
xchg ax, bx
;at this point, ax is unchanged, result is in bx.
```

However, multiplication by a 16-bit register will leave its results in `dx:ax`. Since your example multiplies small numbers, this does not really matter, as the entire result will fit within a 16-bit register.  However, be advised that your `dx` register will be cleared by these code fragments, and if you do multiply larger numbers in the future, be sure to look for the result in `dx:bx`.

Comment: All forms of mul / imul produce the full result.  http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html.  `mul r/m8` puts it in AX, but all the rest put it in [RE]DX:[RE]AX

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the clarification.  So, when multiplying by more than 8-bits, `dx` always gets one for the team.

Comment: @PeterCordes I fixed it.

Comment: Right, unless you use two or three-operand IMUL to not put the high half anywhere.  But 8086 doesn't have that.

Comment: BTW, I don't think the OP wanted to preserve AX, just didn't know how to `mov ax, bx` or something.  If you're writing 8086 code, you definitely don't want to get into the habit of writing slower code to preserve AX around every sequence that needs it.  XCHG is useful (and fast on 8086 where code size is the dominant factor, because there's a form of `xchg ax, reg` that includes the reg in the opcode, so it's one byte.  (this is where 0x90 NOP comes from: `xchg eax, eax`)).  But XCHG is slow on modern CPUs, so again not a good habit.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree, the OP probably did not care to preserve `ax`, and in any case, we usually do not care to preserve `ax`.  But the problem with stackoverflow is that the moment you leave open the possibility for someone to find potential fault with your code, someone *will* find fault with it and downvote. "Oh, you forgot to preserve ax, your code modifies more registers than it needs to, the OP wanted it to behave like a regular multiplication between two registers, what if he puts it in a macro, bla bla blah..."

Comment: That's also why I felt the need to mention `dx`; I am sure the OP could not care less about `dx`.

Comment: Just write code that doesn't suck, and describe what it does.  (i.e. clobbers AX and DX).  The simpler the better, IMO.  You should probably also mention the critical bugfix of changing `mov bx, Ah` to `mov bx, 0Ah`, too!  I mentioned it in a comment on the question already, but since you fixed it, you should mention it, too.)